# vscode python 'format on save' differs from 'format on type'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, format

When i go to new line, formatter behaves one way
For example:
`a=1+2` -> `a = 1 + 2`

But when i press save button, formatter behaves different
For example:
`a=1+2` -> `a = 1+2`

I am using default 'autopep8'
I want 'format on save' behave like 'format on type'

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the use of different formatting types, the file display style is different.

According to your description, it is recommended that you use `"python.formatting.blackPath": "black",` instead of `"python.formatting.autopep8Path": "autopep8",` after entering "`a=1+2`", the effect is the same as
`"editor.formatOnType": true,`:

[image]

Reference: [Formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatterspecific-settings).